# Node-red how to read global var in template node

Tags: node-red

Hi I am facing issue at "template" node. I try to access global variable but i am getting error like "global is not defined". please help me..

Answer (score 9):

It depends which template node you are referring to. The core template node allows you to access flow/global context properties. From the help it provides in the information sidebar:

> It is possible to use a property from the flow context or global context. Just use `{{flow.name}}` or `{{global.name}}`.

This was introduced in Node-RED 0.16 - so has been available for sometime.

If however you are referring to the `ui_template` node, provided as part of the `node-red-dashboard` set of nodes, then no, you cannot access context directly and you should use a Change node to attach any context property to the message you pass to the `ui_template` node.